# Performance between pure static html files and static html files with content loaded via JS & noSQL

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, performance, nosql

Between the following setups, which one would be performing the fastest page load for a front end user. I am only interested in the speed performance for frontend users and not the maintenance requirement for backend developers.

1. A website that only uses static .html files, no JavaScript, no PHP, no server side programming language to render the html. Basically the origins of the internet, where each click on an internal link loads a static .html file. Each page is a pre-created physical .html file on the server.
2. A website with a physical pre-created .html file, however the main content (article) on each page is fetched via Javascript from a noSQL server (Google Cloud Firestore or Fauna DB). Each click on an internal link only replaces the main content of the page via database call. The rest of the website (menu, logo, sidebar, footer) is all static and never needs to reload.
3. A website with a physical pre-created .html file, but the main content (article) on each page itself is fetched via JavaScript from a local JSON file, no database, just a regular .json file in the same directory as the .html file on the same server. Each click on an internal link only replaces the main content of the page using JavaScript (probably vanilla JavaScript using fetch, unless react is somehow faster, which I doubt). The rest of the website (menu, logo, sidebar, footer) is all static and never needs to reload.

Of course server performance and user location does always play a role in speed tests, but for argument sake let’s assume it’s the same user visiting the same web server. Additionally in regards to noSQL, let's say it’s a fast and reliable performing 3rd party server such as Google Cloud Firestore.

Which one of these setups would be the fastest? Has anyone tested this? I heard some people argue that basic static .html files are always fastest, while others argue that a static html file where the content is loaded via JavaScript is faster when navigating internal links once the initial page load is done. Both arguments make sense.

Any major pros or cons for one of the mentioned setups, or past benchmarks?

Comment: This isn't on topic for Stack Overflow, which is meant for help with specific debugging issues, not general architecture questions. Might be more suited to software engineering exchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speed of the webpage has two big components:
A. How fast the server responds/the size of the response
B. How fast the browser can render whatever it fetched

So, static files without JS will be the fastest, there is no delay on the server side, and the browser is very efficient in rendering static assets

The third option is still fast, but slightly slower than the first one as there is some work for the browser exists (transforming the JSON to HTML via JS)

The second option will be the slowest, as it is the only option where the server is not responding instantly with a file, but needs to connect to a DB, fetch the results, transform them, and only then send back.

All of it is relevant only in case we are talking about exactly the same content, but in different forms.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

The question is slightly flawed, but to answer

1. Static content is fastest, the browser will render the content and cache it.
2. Getting content from a database adds overhead to the call and retrieval, the main page will be downloaded once and cached on the client side, the calls for content can not be cached as the browser needs to make the call to see what the content is.  The upside is that the call will only return the content that needs to be displayed and DB searches are pretty quick from the big cloud service providers
3. This option is probably slower than 2, because the whole JSON file will need to be downloaded for the JavaScript to pick out the content for one article from all the content.

I would suggest option 2 is best from a maintainability vs speed point of view as it will only send the required data across the network and the rest is cached.
If you like option 3, have a look at using the browser cache https://web.dev/cache-api-quick-guide/ to cache your JSON file, this way the user will only need to download an updated version when you change the content